next.js, deploy without env files with a yml pipeline
I'm working on creating some YML pipelines in Azure Devops for the release of a Next.js application. I'll start by saying that I don't know this language. I saw that it uses a .env file to manage environment variables.
I created a first version of the pipeline that uses a secret file based on the .env file containing these parameters:

SITECORE_API_KEY
SITECORE_API_HOST
GRAPH_QL_ENDPOINT
JSS_APP_NAME
SITECORE_SITE_NAME
SITECORE_EDGE_CONTEXT_ID
GRAPH_QL_SERVICE_RETRIES
FETCH_WITH
DEBUG PUBLIC_URL
NEXTAUTH_SECRET

It works well but now I would like something more secure, instead of using a file I would like to use global variables present in a library to pass these values. Now I don't know how to do it, I can't find much on the internet but it seems strange to me that something like this can't be done.
In summary, I would need to understand how to pass the values present in the env file during deployment with values that I will retrieve from a variable group within the yaml pipeline.
Anyone have any ideas?
EDIT:
This is my yaml pipeline:
trigger: 
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest' 

stages:
- stage: fedbuild
  displayName: 'Build'
  jobs:
  - job: build
    displayName: 'Front-End Build'
    steps:
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      inputs:
        secureFile: '.env'
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: $(Agent.TempDirectory)
        Contents: '**\.env'
        TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pico-xmcloud-project/src/sxapico'
        OverWrite: true
    
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: "Display Updated token File"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your PowerShell commands here.
          Write-Host "Displaying the Content"
          Get-Content -path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pico-xmcloud-project/src/sxapico/.env

    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '21.7.1'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
      displayName: 'npm install'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pico-xmcloud-project/src/sxapico'

    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'npm bootstrap'
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pico-xmcloud-project/src/sxapico'
        customCommand: 'run bootstrap'
  
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'npm build'
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pico-xmcloud-project/src/sxapico'
        customCommand: 'run next:build'
        verbose: true

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pico-xmcloud-project/src/sxapico'
        Contents: '**/*'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/output'
        CleanTargetFolder: true
        OverWrite: true
      displayName: 'Copy Files to Target'
    
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/nodeapp/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
      displayName: 'Archive files'
    
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
      inputs:
        artifactName: 'package'
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/nodeapp/'
      displayName: 'Publish package'


.env files are intended to be secure method of storing things like API keys, configuration and such. See dotenv npm package. README.md in the github repository explains pretty much all you need to know about .env files. How is this secure? .env files should never be stored in VCS, but set up only locally.

That's true that any part of the process can access the environment variables, but that's not a security issue - if your system is running malicious code, it's compromised long before loading .env file and there is no good protection method against malicious program with the same level of privileges as the encapsulating program.

the code is absolutely not hosted within the git repository, so much so that it has been excluded within the gitignore, the file is hosted within the libraries in the secure file section. I just wanted to know if it is possible to use, instead of a file use a group of variables hosted in azure devops to pass the parameters that the code expects that's all..

Can you share your yaml file used to build the pipeline? So that we can know how you use .env file in your pipeline and give you more accurate suggestion about passing the value from variable group to your code.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT i added my pipeline


Create a variable group and add your variables.
Use the variable group in the yaml.

variables:
- group: {variable group name}


In your Next.js project, you can access these variables using process.env. For example, if you have a variable named SITECORE_API_KEY in your variable group, you can access it in your Next.js project use process.env.SITECORE_API_KEY.

